# Javascript Class Invoke

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm

I am trying to do a Q20-ish game, the problem is when I try to invoque a class in Javascript. See the extract below.

```
var TreeQuestions = require('./Tree.js');

var node = {
    value: null,
    id: null,
    ifAnswer:false,
    No: null,
    Yes: null};

var counter = 0;

node.value= "Root";
node.id=counter;
node.No=null;
nodeYes=null;

TreeQuestions.addYes(node.value,node.id,null);
counter = counter + 1 ;
...
```

On TreeQuestions.addYes an error comes up telling me that the method is undefined.

See my Tree.js file below for further reference.

```
var Tree = {

    //If you need to add the root node, just specify the third parameter as null on any of addYes or addNo function;
    addYes: function(value,id,CurrentNode){
        //create a new item object, place data in
        var node = {
            value: value,
            id: id,
            ifAnswer:false,
            No: null,
            Yes: null};

        //special case: no items in the tree yet
        if (this._root === null){
            this._root = node;
        } else {
            CurrentNode.Yes = node;
        }
    },

    addNo: function(value,id,CurrentNode){
        //create a new item object, place data in
        var node = {
            value: value,
            id: id,
            ifAnswer:false,
            No: null,
            Yes: null};

        //special case: no items in the tree yet
        if (this._root === null){
            this._root = node;
        } else {
            CurrentNode.No= node;
        }
    },

    getNo: function(CurrentNode){
        if(CurrentNode.No != null){
            return CurrentNode.No;
        }else{ 
            return null;
        }
    },

    getYes: function(CurrentNode){
        if(CurrentNode.Yes != null){
            return CurrentNode.Yes;
        } else{
            return null;
        }
    },

    gameBegin: function(){
        currentNode = this._root;

        var response = Yes;
        var win = false;

       while(currentNode != null && win==false){
           if( response=="yes"){
               currentNode = This.getYes(this.currentNode);
               console.log(currentNode.value+"   "+ currentNode.value+"  "+currentNode.ifAnswer.toString())
           } else if(response=="no"){
               currentNode = This.getNo(this.currentNode);
               console.log(currentNode.value+"   "+ currentNode.value+"  "+currentNode.ifAnswer.toString())
           }
       }
    }
};

var node = {
    value: null,
    id: null,
    ifAnswer:false,
    No: null,
    Yes: null
};

function Tree() {
    this._root = null;
}
```

Which seem to be the error? Am I taking a wrong approach to this problem?

Comment: Probably related: https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html - I'm far from a node regular user so I'll leave an actual answer to someone else

Comment: your Tree.js isn't exporting anything

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
var Tree = {
```

And then at the end of Tree.js you have:

```
function Tree() {
    this._root = null;
}
```

It means you have just overridden your Tree object with a function definition.

Also you need to export the literal which is currently assigned to var Tree:

```
module.exports = {
   addYes:...
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
getNo: function(CurrentNode){
    if(CurrentNode.No != null){
      return CurrentNode.No;
    } else{ 
      return null;
    }

},`getNo: function(CurrentNode){
    if(CurrentNode.No != null){
      return CurrentNode.No;
    } else { 
      return null;
    }

},
```

Comment: So... someone corrects your formatting and you reciprocate by tossing insults?